# mySql is not creating new table on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, create-table

Why do I need to reload / refresh / run this script TWICE
to get the new table under the new database that have just been created ?

IOW... This script is working perfectly but not on first run.

Only after refresh it creates the new table.

```
<?php

$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbuserpass = '';
$dbname = 'newDatabase';

$link_id = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
if (!mysql_select_db($dbname, $link_id)){mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE '.$dbname, $link_id);}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: Check the return value of `mysql_query()` and `mysql_error()` to see if there's an error. Side Note: Don't use `mysql_*()` - the functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, if the database didn't exist then it wouldn't select it so the CREATE TABLE would fail.

Try changing the `$sql` query to:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $dbname . "`.`users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

**EDIT:**
As others have suggested, another possible solution would be to call mysql_select_db (or your your favourite newer alternative to the mysql_* functions) but this involves more data transfer to the database so using this method will be slightly more efficient. Although that efficiency will be negligible in this scenario probably!

Comment: Yea, I like this method [ shorter than mysql_select_db($dbname, $link_id); ] THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH !

Answer (score 2):

When the mysql_select_db errors because the database doesn't exist, the `CREATE DATABASE` statement is executed.

Following that, there's no second call to `mysql_select_db` to change to the newly created database.

The `CREATE TABLE` statement is likely encountering a "**no database selected**" type error.

Those calls to mysql_query can raise SQL errors; it's a good idea to check for successful completion, rather than just assuming that everything went to plan.

---

And, for the *love* of all that is *good* and *beautiful* in this world, don't use the **mysql_** interface for new development. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


$link_id = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
if (!mysql_select_db($dbname, $link_id)){
mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE '.$dbname, $link_id);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link_id); //add this
}
```

You basically create the database (when it doesnt exist) but dont then connect to it te first time around - adding that line should fix it.